# HTML div resize issue

Tags: html, css

I have a div and want to change its width but it is changing only up to 1080px. after that it will not increasing.

I want to increase 
 `<div style="height:350px !important;    width:1600px !important;" class="karne_umumi">`  this div tag.

```css
body {
 line-height: 1;
}



table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


body{
    line-height:24px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:16px;
}

img{
    border:0;
}

table{
 width:100%;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
   border:1px solid #000 !important;
     font-size:1.20em !important;
}

table td{
    padding:2px;
    line-height:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
   border-right:1px solid #000; 
}

 table.karne,table.karne td {
     padding:2px 2px !important;
}

table.karne{
 border-bottom: 0px !important;
}


 .karne_umumi {
    background: #ECEEEE;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:720px !important;
    max-width:1080px;
    height:510px !important;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
     margin-left:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
 div.karne_umumi img {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

 div.karne_umumi table td img {
    border: none;
    float: none;
}

 .vereqe_basliq {
    background: #efefee;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    padding:5px;
    margin:auto 1px;
}
 .vereqe_body {
     background: #FFFFFF;
     border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0 auto;
     color: #515658;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     min-height: 300px;
     max-height: 1080px;
     min-width:400px;
     max-width:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
}

.cvb {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
}
.cvb1 {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 width:45px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.cvb2 {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 width:75px;
 
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    
  
 <link href="./files/karne_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    
   <div style="height:350px !important;    width:1600px !important;" class="karne_umumi">   <div class="vereqe_basliq">
        <span style="float: left">place: 1</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 5%;">Exam 9</span>
        <span style="float: right"> Score: 40</span>
   </div>
   <div class="vereqe_body">
      <table class="karne">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width:120px">
                      <div><b>name:</b> XXXXX        </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>surname:</b> YYYYYYYY     </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>father Name:</b> ZZZZZZZZ       </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>grade:</b> 9</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>School:</b> 005</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>District:</b> SSSSSSS</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>Variant:</b>  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>Date:</b> 2018-11-29</div>
            
               </td>
               <td style=" padding: 2px 2px !important; border-right: 0px !important;">
       <div><center><img style="margin-top:-20px;" src="./files/21_logo.png" width="100"></center></div>                  <table>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td><b>Subjects</b></td>
                           <td><b>Answers</b></td>
                           <td><b>Correct</b></td>
                           <td><b>Wrong</b></td>
                           <td><b>Net</b></td>
                           <td><b>Score</b></td>
                           <td><b>SUM</b></td>
                        </tr>
                   
                  
               <tr>
                           <td>Math</td><td><img src="./files/key.png"><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb1">42    </span><span class="cvb1">361   </span><span class="cvb1">54    </span><span class="cvb1">27    </span><span class="cvb2">   D ,    E,A    </span><span class="cvb1">120   </span><span class="cvb1">480   </span><span class="cvb1">0.6   </span><br><img src="./files/stu.png"><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb1">22.5  </span><span class="cvb1">140   </span><span class="cvb1">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb1">200   </span><span class="cvb2">ABCDE,ABCDE,ABCDE</span><span class="cvb1">40    </span><span class="cvb1">132   </span><span class="cvb1">&nbsp;</span></td><td style="background:#dddddd;">10</td><td>20</td><td style="background:#dddddd;">0</td><td>0</td><td rowspan="3">0</td> </tr> 
               </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
  <div style="float:left;"> 
  <div style="margin-left:10px; display:inline-block;">
  <img style="padding-top:4px" src="./files/key.png"> Correct answers
 </div>
 <div style="margin-left:10px; display:inline-block;">
  <img style="padding-top:4px" src="./files/stu.png"> Wrong answers
 </div>
 
 </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

It is a answer sheet for students. I want to all correct answers and students answer be one line. But as it is seen, last two answers from both correct and students answers are goes to down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to increase width of div with class karne_umumi you have to delete or increase max-width in .karne_umumi

```
.karne_umumi {
    background: #ECEEEE;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:720px !important;
```

**max-width:1080px;**

```
    height:510px !important;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
     margin-left:5px;
     border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. i suppose that's what you want.

```css
body {
 line-height: 1;
}



table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


body{
    line-height:24px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:16px;
}

img{
    border:0;
}

table{
 width:100%;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
   border:1px solid #000 !important;
     font-size:1.20em !important;
}

table td{
    padding:2px;
    line-height:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
   border-right:1px solid #000; 
}

 table.karne,table.karne td {
     padding:2px 2px !important;
}

table.karne{
 border-bottom: 0px !important;
}


 .karne_umumi {
    background: #ECEEEE;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:720px !important;
    max-width:1080px;
    height:510px !important;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
     margin-left:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
 div.karne_umumi img {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

 div.karne_umumi table td img {
    border: none;
    float: none;
}

 .vereqe_basliq {
    background: #efefee;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    padding:5px;
    margin:auto 1px;
}
 .vereqe_body {
     background: #FFFFFF;
     border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0 auto;
     color: #515658;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     min-height: 300px;
     max-height: 1080px;
     min-width:400px;
     max-width:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
}

.cvb {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
}
.cvb1 {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 width:45px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.cvb2 {

       font-family:Monaco,Menlo,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#f7f7f9;
 border:1px solid #000;
 margin-left:2px;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 width:75px;
 
 display:inline-block;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    
  
 <link href="./files/karne_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    
   <div style="height:350px !important;    width:1600px !important;" class="karne_umumi">   <div class="vereqe_basliq">
        <span style="float: left">place: 1</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 5%;">Exam 9</span>
        <span style="float: right"> Score: 40</span>
   </div>
   <div class="vereqe_body">
      <table class="karne">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width:120px">
                      <div><b>name:</b> XXXXX        </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>surname:</b> YYYYYYYY     </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>father Name:</b> ZZZZZZZZ       </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>grade:</b> 9</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>School:</b> 005</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>District:</b> SSSSSSS</div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>Variant:</b>  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div><b>Date:</b> 2018-11-29</div>
            
               </td>
               <td style=" padding: 2px 2px !important; border-right: 0px !important;">
       <div><center><img style="margin-top:-20px;" src="./files/21_logo.png" width="100"></center></div>                  <table>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td><b>Subjects</b></td>
                           <td><b>Answers</b></td>
                           <td><b>Correct</b></td>
                           <td><b>Wrong</b></td>
                           <td><b>Net</b></td>
                           <td><b>Score</b></td>
                           <td><b>SUM</b></td>
                        </tr>
                   
                  
               <tr>
                           <td>Math</td><td><img src="./files/key.png"><div class="flex"><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb1">42    </span><span class="cvb1">361   </span><span class="cvb1">54    </span><span class="cvb1">27    </span><span class="cvb2">   D ,    E,A    </span><span class="cvb1">120   </span><span class="cvb1">480   </span><span class="cvb1">0.6   </span></div><br><img src="./files/stu.png">
                 <div class="flex"><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">D</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">A</span><span class="cvb">B</span><span class="cvb">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb">C</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb">E</span><span class="cvb1">22.5  </span><span class="cvb1">140   </span><span class="cvb1">&nbsp;</span><span class="cvb1">200   </span><span class="cvb2">ABCDE,ABCDE,ABCDE</span><span class="cvb1">40    </span><span class="cvb1">132   </span><span class="cvb1">&nbsp;</span>
                   </div>
                   </td><td style="background:#dddddd;">10</td><td>20</td><td style="background:#dddddd;">0</td><td>0</td><td rowspan="3">0</td> </tr> 
               </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
  <div style="float:left;"> 
  <div style="margin-left:10px; display:inline-block;">
  <img style="padding-top:4px" src="./files/key.png"> Correct answers
 </div>
 <div style="margin-left:10px; display:inline-block;">
  <img style="padding-top:4px" src="./files/stu.png"> Wrong answers
 </div>
 
 </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```